# Fragmentation Analysis stored procedure is taking a lot of time to execute

Tags: sql-server

The stored procedure used for analyzing the fragmentation percentage takes more than 4 to 5 hrs to execute. I'm not much expert in writing and analyzing queries. Any help/suggestions to get this executed fast would be much appreciated. There is a job created to run this stored procedure , and the job duration is more than 4 to 5 hrs every day.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fragmentation_Analysis]  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Dbid Int, @Objectid Int, @Indexid Int, 
            @Partitioncount Bigint, @Schemaname Sysname, 
            @Objectname Sysname
    DECLARE @Indexname Sysname, @Partitionnum Bigint, 
            @Partitions Bigint, @Frag Float, @DefragCount Int
    DECLARE @Qry Varchar(Max)

    SET @Dbid = Db_Id()
    SET @Qry = ''

    IF (SELECT Object_Id('Tempdb..#FragTabInfo')) IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #FragTabInfo

    CREATE TABLE #FragTabInfo
    (
         Objectid Int, 
         Indexid Int, 
         Partitionnum Int, 
         Frag Float
    )

    SET @Qry = 'INSERT INTO #FragTabInfo (Objectid, Indexid, Partitionnum, Frag) 
                    SELECT 
                        Object_Id AS Objectid, 
                        Index_Id AS Indexid, 
                        Partition_Number AS Partitionnum,  
                        Avg_Fragmentation_In_Percent AS Frag
                    FROM
                        Sys.Dm_Db_Index_Physical_Stats (' + Convert(Varchar(9),@Dbid) + ', Null, Null , Null, ''Limited'')
                    WHERE Avg_Fragmentation_In_Percent > 10.0 
                      AND Index_Id > 0'

    EXEC (@Qry)

    SELECT @DefragCount = COUNT(*) FROM #FragTabInfo

    IF (@DefragCount IS NULL OR @DefragCount = 0)
        PRINT 'Fragmentation% is <= 10.0 for all tables'

    DECLARE Partitions CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * 
        FROM #FragTabInfo 
        ORDER BY Object_Name(Objectid)

    OPEN Partitions

    FETCH NEXT FROM Partitions INTO @Objectid, @Indexid, @Partitionnum, @Frag

    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Objectname = O.Name, @Schemaname = S.Name
        FROM Sys.Objects AS O
        JOIN Sys.Schemas AS S ON S.Schema_Id = O.Schema_Id
        WHERE O.Object_Id = @Objectid

        SELECT @Indexname = Name 
        FROM Sys.Indexes
        WHERE Object_Id = @Objectid AND Index_Id = @Indexid
 
        SELECT @Partitioncount = COUNT(*) 
        FROM Sys.Partitions
        WHERE Object_Id = @Objectid AND Index_Id = @Indexid

        -- 30 Is An Arbitrary Decision Point At Which To Switch Between Reorganizing And Rebuilding
        IF @Frag < 30.0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Qry = 'ALTER INDEX ' + @Indexname + ' ON ' + @Schemaname + '.' + @Objectname + ' REORGANIZE'

            EXEC(@Qry)
        END

        IF @Frag >= 30.0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Qry = 'ALTER INDEX ' + @Indexname +' ON ' + @Schemaname + '.' + @Objectname + ' REBUILD'

            EXEC (@Qry)
        END

        PRINT 'Executed ' + @Qry + ' with fragmentation %' + Convert(Varchar(9),@Frag)

        IF @Qry != ''
            IF CharIndex('Reorganize', @Qry) = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @Qry = 'UPDATE STATISTICS ' + @Objectname + ' WITH SAMPLE 30 ROWS'
                PRINT @Qry

                EXEC (@Qry)
            END
    
        FETCH NEXT FROM Partitions INTO @Objectid, @Indexid,  @Partitionnum, @Frag
    END

    CLOSE Partitions
    DEALLOCATE Partitions

    IF (SELECT Object_Id('Tempdb..#FragTabInfo')) IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #FragTabInfo
END
```

Comment: How many times has this process _acted_ on its discovery, and how many times has that action _actually helped_ your system in a meaningful and measurable way?

Comment: Are you seeing execution plans with a lot of bad row estimates? The output of `update statistics`  is used to produce histograms with 200 buckets (see [sys.dm_db_stats_histogram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-histogram-transact-sql)), so I don't see how that can be generating useful data by sampling only 30 rows.

Comment: And I don't mean "it reduced fragmentation on `table x` by `y %`!" I mean what positive result did that actually provide your system? My point is that this will take a lot less time [if you stop running it in the first place](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/). (Also if you're going to keep doing this work for questionable gain, please use [Ola's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/) instead of re-inventing the wheel.)

Comment: There is no magic trick to make this fast. If you're going to read `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` then this is a function of only (a) the size of your database and (b) the capacity of your I/O.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't find any use of this SP but it was created by the application team and now they are questioning us why the SP is taking more time to execute.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Do I have to use 'Intelligent Index Maintenance' from Ola's script?

Comment: Do you have to? I have no idea. Have you answered (for yourself) any of the questions I asked above? Most importantly: is performing this index maintenance every night _actually doing anything for you_?